# How to send Data from Fragment to other Fragment inside FirebaseAdapter, using model.class to getPid

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

i have being trying to solve this problem for while thought, i'm trying to pass the data from Fragment to other Fragment, the model.getPid suggesting me to be static!, and after running the app and clicking on the image then the app crachs!
thanks in advance!

```
 holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            ProductsDetailsFragment fragment = new ProductsDetailsFragment();
                            Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
                            b1.putString("pid", Products.getPid());
                            fragment.setArguments(b1);
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager =  
                            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
                                    .addToBackStack(null)
                                    .commit();
```

this is from the second Fragment

```
 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        productID= bundle.getString("pid");
        getProductDetails(productID);
    }
```

in the FirebaseAdapter when i pass the ProductTD, it returns null

```
  private void getProductDetails(String productID) {
    DatabaseReference productRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
    productRef.child(productID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
```

this is from Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
```

Comment: If you are using Navigation Component, then DON'T replace the NavHostFragment. Use the Navigation Component to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

here is your error `Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductsDetailsFragment.class);
                             intent.putExtra("pid", model.getPid());
                               startActivity(intent)`

remove this you can use intent for fragment

Comment: yeah i just deleted, actually the intent was in comment, i wasn't using it, well do you have any idea where the problem could be ! thanks

Comment: b1.putString("pid", Products.getPid()); check its come in string or int if its come in convert it into string

Comment: productID= bundle.getString("pid"); use log here i think you dont get the data here

Comment: i've solved the problem by replacing getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(); to getFragmentManager().